# Sending parameter to iframe using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I am working on special project and I almost finished it. My problem is `*sending parameter to iframe*`.

My aim is to create **simple** editor like codepen or jsfiddle.

**These are my ajax codes:**

```
        $.ajax({
            data: {html: html, css: css, js: js},
            success: function(r) {
                if(r) {
                    $("#preview").html(r.preview);
                } else {
                    alert("error");
                }
            }
        });
```

**My ajax.php**

```
$html = $_POST["html"];
$css = $_POST["css"];
$js = $_POST["js"];

$r = array();



function d($html, $css, $js) {
    $iframe .= '<iframe src="iframe.php">';

    $iframe .= '</iframe>';
    return $iframe;
}

$r["preview"] = d($html, $css, $js);
echo json_encode($r);
```

**And finally my iframe.php**

```
function prev($html = "", $css = "", $js = "") {
    $iframe .= '<html>';
    $iframe .= '<head>';
    $iframe .= '<style>' . $css . '</style>';
    $iframe .= '<script>' . $js . '</script>';
    $iframe .= '<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';
    $iframe .= '</head>';
    $iframe .= '<body>';
    $iframe .= $html;
    $iframe .= '</body>';
    $iframe .= '</html>';
    return $iframe;
}
echo prev(); // which parameters I use?
```

It is working but I didnt send parameter which comes from textarea? I didnt associate ajax.php and iframe.php.

Comment: Can't you set the `iframe` already fixed on the page, and then post the values directly to iframe.php, instead of passing through another page?

Comment: `$iframe .= '<iframe src="iframe.php?html='.$html.'&css='.$css.'&js='.$js.'">';` I used like this at that time `"` is not used. But I believe I can solve with POST method.

Comment: I mean, why are you creating the `<iframe>` on the ajax response? Why dont you keep the iframe already created, and then post a form with a target to the iframe?

Comment: I analyzed codepen,jsfiddle and the others. Using iframe is the best solution. Other ways are wrong and inadequate. There is a spot I missed.

Comment: I'm not telling you not to use the `iframe`... I'm just saying that you should already set the `<iframe>` on the page!! JsFiddle itself already have all four iframes set on the page... It does not create it dynamically!!!

Comment: Yeah I see, I tried this, At that time I dont handle iframes. This was interesting problem. I want to start some jquery codes in my iframe page.

Comment: The problem with your approach is that your iframe.php will be loaded only after your ajax request is returned, and the `<iframe>` is created... So it will have absolutely no relation with the ajax request. It is impossible to send information from one request to another except through get parameters written on the url, that you already figured on your comment...

Comment: I see. But there is one site. It works like I said. I can't give link. Thanks for your helps, I am trying still.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding a bit of what actually happens here. Let me see if I can explain what is currently happening and where I think you should go from here.

### The 'Talk'

Let's think of a user's page request as a conversation with your server. Here's kind of how it's going down:

- **Browser:** Hey server, can you give me blah.html?
- **Server:** Sure, here it is.
- **Browser:** Thanks!
- **Browser:** Uh server, AJAX is telling me I need ajax.php. Can I have the output of that?
- **Server:** Sure, here it is.
- **Browser:** Great!
- **Browser:** Ok well ajax.php told me I need to load iframe.php. Can I get that?
- **Server:** Sure, here it is.
- **iframe.php:** As far as I'm concerned, **Browser** requested me. I know nothing of ajax.php

... and that's where you're stuck. All that HTML, CSS, and JS was sent to `ajax.php`, and that page didn't really do anything with it. Yeah, it printed out an `iframe` tag with the source set as `iframe.php`, but that page has no idea about all that stuff you gave to `ajax.php`.

### My Suggestion

After reading through the comments you posted, it looks like you're trying to mimic a user-input code previewer, if I'm not mistaken. There are plenty of reasons why sites like JSFiddle use `iframe` elements, one of which is to prevent the user's script from *reaching outside of its realm to manipulate stuff on the page*. If you would like to implement this, your code structure needs to change.

First, your HTML page where all this is happening should have your `iframe` element already on the page. Just don't set its `src` target yet. For example, something like this will suffice:

```
<iframe id="preview"></iframe>
```

Second, I would use a form that has its target set as the `iframe`. This allows you to POST the data they type to the PHP file, then essentially send the output of that file to the `iframe` to be loaded. A very simple example might look like this:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" target="preview">
    <textarea name="html"></textarea>
    <textarea name="css"></textarea>
    <textarea name="js"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Run!" />
</form>
```

**submit.php:**

```
$html = $_POST['html'];
$css = $_POST['css'];
$js = $_POST['js'];

// Using your code from before...
function prev($html = "", $css = "", $js = "") {
    $iframe = '<html>';
    $iframe .= '<head>';
    $iframe .= '<style>' . $css . '</style>';
    $iframe .= '<script>' . $js . '</script>';
    $iframe .= '<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';
    $iframe .= '</head>';
    $iframe .= '<body>';
    $iframe .= $html;
    $iframe .= '</body>';
    $iframe .= '</html>';
    return $iframe;
}

echo prev($html, $css, $js);
```

**WARNING:** This is untested code.

Comment: Thanks for long reply. I understand all things. I am using iframe because codepen is also using iframe. Also to run JS codes, using iframe is necessary because eval() does not help to run script in iframe. Thank you also for Talk :)

Comment: I know this solution. Using target is working problem. But I am trying to make editor with jQuery/Ajax. Thanks for example. That is exactly working.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Did this solve your problem? If so, please mark it as correct so others know you have been helped. If not, please explain why you need to use jQuery's AJAX feature.

Comment: So you want it to dynamically change the preview after they typed things in? This could be an issue if you allow JavaScript code to be inserted because what if they haven't finished the HTML to match up with it? If you trigger the preview when the textarea loses focus, then the JS code might fail. If you implement any sort of error handling, this could give false warnings.

Comment: Warnings are not important. Important thing is to run JS codes :)

Comment: Well, in that case, you won't even need any server side code. Just use `$('#preview').contents()` to reach inside the DOM of the `iframe` and update the HTML/JS/CSS that way. Though I'm not sure how this would work with JS functions like `$(document).ready()`. You might have to manually fire that event.

Comment: I tried this. In `contents()` method, JS code didn't work. I didn't reach `<script>` tags.

Comment: You should have been able to reach the script tag. In any case, you could always append a new `script` tag with the contents of the user's input to the end of the body. Then always just clear out the contents of the body on each change. Again, you might need to trigger the `ready` event on the `iframe`.

Comment: I understand, can you give me a simple example? thanks for reply.

Comment: I have tried creating an example for you, but I have had a lot of difficulty getting the JS code to run in the context of the `iframe`. Everything I have tried has correctly inserted the code into the `iframe`, but when it is executed, its scope is the whole parent document, not just the `iframe`. I highly suggest following what other services do and submit to a form.

Comment: I achived this yesterday night. I use ajax.php, iframe.php, iframe in index.php and some js codes.

Comment: Ok, I still suggest reducing your server-side code down to one PHP file in this case. It will improve performance and reduce complexity. Nonetheless, if my answer has adequately helped you, please mark it as correct so others know you have been helped.